# Однородными обязательно будет одиночное определение и причастный оборот - так ли это?

Tags: однородные-члены, определения

Правильно ли такое утверждение:

Однородными обязательно будет одиночное определение и причастный оборот, например: Они обедали в небольшой, плохо убранной комнате. Мы долго шли по сырой, нехотя просыхающей земле  Подробнее: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/kak-otlichit-odnorodnyie-i-neodnorodnyie-opredeleniya.html

У Розенталя есть и такие примеры: чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину потёртый воротник; большой собранный автором материал и т. п. — первое определение относится к сочетанию второго определения с существительным;

Comment: Сами же и ответили на свой вопрос. Не стоит принимать всерьёз всякие неизвестно откуда взявшиеся "образовательные" сайты (кстати, ещё один пример неоднородных определений).

Answer (score 2):

Я искала через отрицание. Два сайта говорят, что таки необязательно. И преподают (якобы) такое в школах, на показательных уроках, со слайдами - чтоб запоминалось, как впечатывалось.

> В комнату вбежала ***маленькая*** громко ***смеющаяся*** девочка.
>   (Маленькая, смеющаяся – неоднородные определения, между ними нельзя
>   поставить союз ***и***.)

Ну, стала я [эту девочку](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/234-odnorodnyeineodnorodnyeopredeleniya.html) дальше раскручивать - попала в восьмой класс...

> В комнату вбежала ***веселая***, громко ***смеющаяся*** девочка.
>   (Весёлая, смеющаяся – однородные определения, выражающие настроение,
>   состояние, между ними можно поставить союз ***и***.)
>
> ---
>
> В комнату вбежала ***маленькая*** громко ***смеющаяся*** девочка. (Маленькая, смеющаяся – неоднородные определения, между ними нельзя
>   поставить союз ***и***.)

**[слайды](https://infourok.ru/prezentaciya-klass-odnorodnie-i-neodnorodnie-opredeleniya-2447788.html)**

---

Сайт, которому можно доверять - [Издательство «ЛИЦЕЙ»](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/713-232_odnorodnye_i_neodnorodnye_opredeleniya.html) - говорит:

> Запомните: несогласованные определения обычно являются однородными, то
>   есть разделяются запятыми. Однородными ***обычно*** являются сочетания
>   согласованных и несогласованных определений.

"Обычно" - это я выделила. Что предполагает: возможны варианты.

Comment: В вопросе нет несогласованных определений. Последнее правило к вопросу не относится. Не так ли?

Comment: "Лицей" относит этот случай к однородным без исключения:  *•за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом, то есть причастием с зависимым словом*


Чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы.